# Deployment script fails when on "npm ci" line (errno -39) but typed manually all works smoothly

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

I have a simple deployment script of my Laravel app in runcloud.

```
git merge

composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
composer dump-autoload -o

php artisan migrate --force

npm ci
npm run production

php artisan queue:restart
```

No rocket science. As soon as I hit deploy a modal pops up with error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Installing
>   dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file Nothing to install
>   or update Generating optimized autoload files
>
> > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> >     @php artisan package:discover --ansi Generating optimized autoload files
> >     Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> >     @php artisan package:discover --ansi npm WARN prepare removing existing node_modules/ before installation npm ERR! path
> >     /home/runcloud/webapps/my-app/node_modules/lodash npm ERR!
> >     code ENOTEMPTY npm ERR! errno -39 npm ERR! syscall rmdir npm ERR!
> >     ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir
> >     '/home/runcloud/webapps/my-app/node_modules/lodash'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/runcloud/.npm/_logs/2019-09-03T05_31_56_253Z-debug.log

Based on the error I assume it fails as soon as it hits `npm ci`.

Weird, `npm ci` should remove `node_modules` and perform simple installation of all dependencies without touching the lock file.

**When I ssh into the server and manually continue typing commands** after where it failed (so I type manually `npm ci` and then `npm run production` **everything works smoothly**.

Finally I restart queue and that's it. Where's the culprit?

Comment: from where you are using the commands a php file http call?

Comment: Then the user which running these commands will be apache2 not the user with which you have connected the ssh

Comment: So definitely a permission issue will be raised.

Comment: If you are not using the web hook than also check from which user you are using `npm ci`? if it is not same than it also a permission issue while installing dependencies.